# How to auto-update app iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, auto-update

So I am making currency tracker ap for iOS. Currently I've managed to extract API of tracker and present it as nice label on my Main.storyboard. When I try to run my app I get latest currency value but it doesn't refresh itself after few minutes with new data. My question is how do I make app refresh itself every minute or so, so user can always be up to date with currency value.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getJSON { (usdPrice) -> Void in
        let usdPriceText = usdPrice.description
        self.bitcoinValue.stringValue = usdPriceText

        print(usdPrice)
    }
}

func getJSON(completion: (Double) -> Void) {
    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let usdPrice = swiftyJSON["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"].doubleValue
            completion(usdPrice)
        } else {
            print("There was an error!")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    }




}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to "stack overflow" I would love to help you with this question but first I need to know where you are querying for this information. Perhaps try editing your post and inserting the code you are using to query the information and tell us where it is located. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating the data on a regular basis (like every minute, as you mentioned), you would want to use an `NSTimer`. They allow you to run a function each time the specified amount of time has passed.

```
let updateTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(TIME_BETWEEN_CALLS, target: self, selector: Selector("FUNCTION"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);
```

- `TIME_BETWEEN_CALLS` means the time in seconds between the call of your update function.
- `FUNCTION` specifies which function to be called by the timer.
- If you would like to stop automatic updates at some time, call `updateTimer.invalidate()`

[Here's some more information about timers I found to be quite useful.](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/swift-nstimer-tutorial-lets-create-a-counter-application/)

Comment: what should my code look like on part  selector: Selector(?)
Thanks for help

Comment: You need the name of the function you want to call. If you have an update routine `func update() { }` then in the timer definition you would have to put `selector: Selector("update")`

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I still get pretty big error message after the time interval has passed. It says:

`2016-01-05 00:46:36.600 Bitfo[22124:1699411] -[Bitfo.ViewController getJSON]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000100090
2016-01-05 00:46:36.601 Bitfo[22124:1699411] -[Bitfo.ViewController getJSON]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000100090
2016-01-05 00:46:36.603 Bitfo[22124:1699411]`

Comment: Hm. Judging from that error, you were trying to call `getJSON` (am I right?). As far as I know, you cannot call a function that takes arguments (honestly, I don't fully understand your `getJSON`. Does it even take arguments?)

Comment: i did use getJSON. getJSON takes API from web page and takes string value of currency from it, and then prints it.

Comment: Not to say it's the best and prettiest way to do it, but try making a `func update() { getJSON(arguments) }` and then call that from the Selector.

Comment: but getJSON has no arguments

Comment: That's weird... Sorry, but I fear I can't help you further, this always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to fetch your value from the API every time your view controller is loaded (when the app starts, when the app is resumed from background), you should call your API method asynchronously from within the viewWillAppear method on your view controller.  viewWillAppear gets called every time the view is about to be shown.  You could also look at other view lifecycle methods to determine when is the best time to reload your data.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    updateCurrencyDataAsync()   //Your API method call
}
```